# Global SQL Database

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm working on a PHP script that does multiple different things. However an aspect of it is perplexing me and I am not sure if it is possible. Let's say we have a user, and they add people's names to a list that are banned from using their website. So they enter a users name and it gets entered into a local database. What if I wanted it so that everyone that uses this script can contribute. I.e when a user bans someone from their site, their name is added to a "global" list that is not on their server. Each person would contribute to the list by banning bad users.

I had a few ideas, that maybe you could make a connection to this global database within the script, however this would compromise security as the connection information would be able to be seen by the script users.

I then thought if you could host an external PHP file on a server that was read only, and it had all the code. I.e the connection and the queries to add to the database. I'm not 100% sure if this is possible.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can connect to Databases that are not hosted on the same server. Or as your last statement depicts; you could create a php page "API" that does the insert, but setup something on that page to authenticate each user before they can insert. just my 2 cents :D

Comment: I like the idea. Require each user to have some sort of unique auth key that has to be validated before allowing access

Answer (score 0):

You may have a common cross-domain dataBase and all users may connect from different websites and insert records about banned users. If Mysql will be necessary to change bind-address parameter inside /etc/mysql/my.cnf file.

Comment: Would this cross domain database not require a password that would have to be specified when make the connection? Would this not compromise security

Comment: You may have a php on your server, which connect to dataBase. Other websites may run your php and you may check security through htaccess (they may run your php just from domain you configure)